# order of events on click on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a normal link on my website, and I want to add tracking for it.  I could envision a bunch of ways to do this, but I've settled on this as being really easy by writing a small jquery function, and dropping a small snippet in my  tags:

```
<a href="newpage.html" onclick="saveClick(paramofpageclickhere);">click me!</a>
```

javascript:

```
function saveClick(someparamhere){
  $.ajax({
   url: "somepage.php",
   data: {param:someparamhere}
  });
}
```

Now, I know my syntax might be bad, I'm just asking about the overall concept here.  When you click the link, I want javascript to issue the call to saveClick which immediately makes an ajax call. There's no success handler because I don't really care if or what gets returned.  I'll just have somepage.php log the event.  Then, after all of that, I want the  tag to go to it's href.

Is that the case?  Will the ajax call be issued before the document goes to the other page? Will this work in all cases?

Has anybody ever done something like this? Any experience would be appreciated ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure the AJAX call goes through you could do:

```
<a href="newpage.html" data-parameters="paramofpageclickhere">click me!</a>

$('[data-parameters]').bind('click', function (event) {
    //cache this element to use in AJAX function
    var $this = $(this);

    //prevent the default naviation
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       url: "somepage.php",
       data: {param:$this.attr('data-parameters')}
       success : function () {

           //now navigate to the requested page
           location = $this[0].href;
       }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

`$.ajax()` exposes a `timeout` function:

> **timeoutNumber**
>
> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override
>   any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts
>   at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in
>   progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible
>   for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and
>   below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the
>   request times out; accessing any object members may throw an
>   exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be
>   cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after
>   the timeout period.

So you could set a `timeout` and an `error` function that mimics the `success` function. The documentation does state that: `it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent` but if your `timeout` is a very small (maybe zero) delay then it could reduce the lag between the user clicking the link and the browser loading the new page.

Comment: ohh, i think i like that. that would degrade nicely for non-javascript browsers, and it can still be crawled by bots and whatnot successfully who don't pay attention to the javascript stuff. is that correct? are there any downsides to doing this?

Comment: i guess *technically* you would waste some time waiting for the ajax call to return before you change your page, that may be noticeable in some cases.

Comment: @Landon Yeah that could be a negative user experience but check-out the `timeout` option for `$.ajax()`, it may be more like what you want.

Comment: @jasper, since you use data attributes you can use `$this.data('parameters')`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks for the advise. I can't believe I haven't taken a look at that yet, it's approx. 75% faster to use `$.data(element, key, val)` than `$(element).attr(key, value)`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr-2

Comment: I updated this jsperf to append the output to the DOM so you can verify the data and it seems that `$.data()` is returning `undefined` (I was not using it properly) which means that `$obj.attr()` is the fastest method: http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr-2/2

Answer (score 0):

I simply wouldn't do that... it could bring to situation your onclick event isn't fired.
I think it would be better to call a javascript function on click that does your ajax call and then bring the user to the target page.

You can do this, for example, this way:

```
<a href="javascript:myfunc(paramofpageclickhere)">...</a>
```

your javascript function then, shall be something like:

```
myfunc(paramofpageclickhere) {
  //do ajax call
  saveClick(someparamhere);
  //go to target page
  location.href = "target.htm";
}
```

Comment: **Hint:  he's using jQuery.**  So bind the click event to the anchor element and remove that inline JS.

Comment: Yes, as in Jasper answer, of course... I'm definetly not used to "custom html tags" like "data-parameters"... do they validate? And are they cross-browser compliant?

Comment: AFAIK, yes & yes.  Of course, you could also look at text of link itself instead and redirect based on that too.

Comment: Great to hear (...of course I meant are they "generally" compliant to w3c validation and are they cross-browser compatible). Also, nice point looking at link text and basing redirect to that in a way to avoid the use of them (of course this would involve some extra care and some rules forming those links)